# Install Windows Media Player 12 on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-media-player, compatibility

Is it possible to install Windows Media Player 12 in Windows XP SP2?

Comment: Did you even try it? If so, did something go wrong? Asking if something is possible without trying it first or doing any research on it isn't really prudent.

Comment: Off topic, but is there a reason you aren't updating to SP3?

Comment: You'd be better off _not_ using WMP12 IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

It's only available on Windows 7.

> Note: Available only in Windows 7. Windows Media Player 12 comes as part of Windows 7 and is not available as a separate download. 
>   ([source](http://Windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/Windows-media-player-12))

Answer (score 0):

What are you hoping on using Windows Media Player for? If you're looking for media streaming, Zune Software can be installed in Windows XP SP3 and will share media with an XBox 360. (It's also a much nicer media player than WMP).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know,it is not possible.update to 7 if you want it,or stick to xp and wmp11.